# Opening a presenter in a new window in GWTP

Tags: uibinder, gwt-platform, gwtp

Currently, i have to implement a print functionality. I had used a pop up presenter on click of a print button, to print the contents of only the pop up panel. but its also printing the contents of the background of the popup panel. Is there any way, for opening a presenter in a new browser window other than pop up? please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following when you press Print:

```
String url = Window.Location
        .createUrlBuilder()
        .setHash(yourPrintingPresenterToken).buildString();
Window.open(url, "_blank", null);
```

You have to transfer your current state to the new presenter somehow, possibly with parametrized token.